# Why doesn't the use of strictly conforming programs and conforming implementations ensure absolute portability?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, portability, c11

C11, 4. Conformance, footnote 5 (emphasis added):

> Strictly conforming programs are intended to be *maximally* portable among conforming implementations.

Why does the combination of `strictly conforming programs && conforming implementations` lead to a gradation of portability (i.e. *maximally*)?

In other words, why doesn't the combination of `strictly conforming programs && conforming implementations` lead to absolute portability?

What are the obstacles / challenges to ensure absolute portability?

Comment: Does a strictly conforming program allow implementation-defined behaviour?

Comment: @dyp: No. C 4 5: A *strictly conforming program* “shall not produce output dependent on any unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior,…”

Comment: “Absolute portability” is not defined in the C standard. You have to define it. Then we can discuss whether it differs from maximally portable. Strictly conforming programs generally will not work with FORTRAN compilers. They will vary in execution time depending on compiler quality and target processor, so code suitable for real-time use in one C implementation may not work in another C implementation. Although one might reason that execution time is unspecified, so any program that depends on it is not strictly conforming.

Comment: There are many things beyond the standard's scope which affect portability. Memory mapping, endianess, stack use etc. The C standard only describes the generic C language, it doesn't describe generic computers.

Comment: A strictly conforming program can use conditional features that some implementation might not support (see C11/C18 footnote 3). That is one source of non-portability.

Comment: @Lundin. You are right and it is a real world cause for portability problems. But any program relying on endianness, existance of a specific size for int types etc. depends on unspecified or implementation specified details and is not a strictly conforming program.

Comment: You could think for instance about the environmental limits in C17 5.2.4.1.  The DeathStation 9000 compiler could say "the maximum number of function parameters is 3, unless your program is  identical to the one my cousin Ted wrote in 1993 that has a function with exactly 127 parameters, and whose source code we keep locked up in a filing cabinet in a disused lavatory with a sign saying Beware of the Leopard".  Then a "strictly conforming" program involving a function with 4 parameters would be rejected by this "conforming implementation".

Comment: @SergeBallesta No, endianess for example is not explicitly specified as implementation-defined. Nor is the existence of a stack etc - these are things simply beyond the scope of the C standard.

Comment: @NateEldredge I believe you mean DeathStation (ISO) 9899  :)

Comment: @Lundin: Implementations must define the order of bytes, per C 2018 6.2.6.1 2.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Aha, indeed. So it was a bad example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard covers both hosted and freestanding implementations. There is (and could be) no "absolute portability" between the two. For hosted implementations in particular, strict compliance guarantees portability, per the same *Conformance* section ([C11 4.5-6](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p6)):

> 5. ***A strictly conforming program shall*** *use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard. It* ***shall not*** *produce output dependent on any unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior,* ***and shall not*** *exceed any minimum implementation limit.*
> 6. *The two forms of conforming implementation are hosted and freestanding.* ***A conforming hosted implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program.*** *A conforming freestanding implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program in which the use of the features specified in the library clause (clause 7) is confined to [...]*

---

[ *EDIT* ] As pointed out by [@Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) in comments below, the statement that a conforming (hosted) implementation "*shall* ***accept*** *any strictly conforming program*" does not amount to a guarantee that it will "*be able to* ***translate and execute***" the same strictly conforming program.

This is because the [5.2.4 Environmental Limits](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4) section lists a number of minimum limits, but only requires that "*the implementation shall be able to* ***translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance*** *of every one of the following limits*".

In other words, even if a strictly conforming program follows [4.5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p5) and does "*not exceed any minimum implementation limit*", there is still no guarantee by the letter of the C law that the implementation will be able to succesfully compile and run it. As [@Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin) put it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3444206) to a related question: "*a "hello world" program isn't strictly conforming*".

Or, as Derek M. Jones commented in The New C Standard:

> The topic of a perverse implementation, one that can
> successfully translate a single program containing all of these limits but no other program, crops up from
> time to time. Although of theoretical interest, this discussion is of little practical interest, because writing
> a translator that only handled a single program would probably require more effort than writing one that
> handled programs in general.

Comment: One problem is that there are a number of practical environmental limits (such as the maximum amount of memory that can be allocated with malloc) which are not covered by the documented "minimum implementation limits."

Comment: @ChrisDodd Right of course, and a good point, but that's beyond the control of the *language* standard. The same `malloc` may work now and fail on the next run, same machine, same implementation. There is only so much the *language* standard can guarantee. I guess that's why it's written as "*shall* ***accept*** *any strictly conforming program*", rather than "*run*" or "*execute reproducibly*".

Comment: @dxiv: But there's also environmental limits on translation, which might prevent your program from being accepted if they are exceeded.

Comment: @NateEldredge My reading of "*a strictly conforming program [...] shall not exceed any minimum implementation limit*" is that, for example, a program with 127 [levels of nested blocks](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1) is strictly conforming, while one with 128 levels may be conforming but not *strictly* conforming.

Comment: But an implementation is only required to accept *at least one* program that has at least 127 levels.  It does not have to accept *every* program that stays within those limits, and in particular it does not have to accept yours.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for pointing that out, guess I read it too fast the first time around. I edited the answer to cover that part, though it's less and less clear what "*accept*" is supposed to mean in 4.6.

Comment: Also conforming freestanding implementations need not support all library headers, just the ones listed in 4/6.

Comment: @Lundin Right, that's the part that I snipped out of the 4.6 quote to keep the focus on hosted implementations. For the record, the headers required of a freestanding implementation are `<float.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, and `<stdnoreturn.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

Maximal portability should be understood as a conservative wording. A strictly conformant program should have the same observable behaviour on any conformant implementation.

Yet the portability may not be *absolute* because some implementations can be wrong for some specific parts of the standard. An example would be optional parts where specific constants should be declared if the option is/is not implemented. And the option is or is not there, but the constant is not... Or an implementation can be *mixed version* conformant: it is fully conformant only to a very old version of the standard and almost conformant to last version except for some details. Or a defect regarding the standard exists and has not yet been fixed. Unfortunately many real world implementations fall in those categories, so the nice program that should work fine on every *conformant* implementation still has problem on a commonly used implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Because different implementations are used for different purposes, and target different platforms with different abilities, any attempt to identify a category of programs that all implementations would be required to process meaningfully would either need to exclude all programs that perform jobs which some implementations would be incapable of doing, or brand as non-conforming implementations that would be suitable for many but not all of the tasks for which people use the C programming language.

The authors of the Standard recognized that the most practical solution to this problem was to recognize that people seeking to design quality implementations for many platforms and purposes would seek to process usefully a wider range of programs than required by the Standard, and treat support for such programs as a Quality of Implementation issue outside the Standard's jurisdiction.  Unfortunately, the authors of C89 and all later version of the Standard deliberately avoided expressing such intention in any way that might suggest that some C implementations are inferior to others for many purposes.

A solution to this problem, if it wouldn't be politically untenable, would be for the Standard to specify means by which programs can indicate anything special they might need from implementations, and specify that (1) conforming implementations may reject any program for any reason, though quality implementations shouldn't do so needlessly, and (2) implementations *MUST*, as a condition of conformance, reject any programs which they could not *otherwise* process in conforming fashion.  That would make it possible to have a category of programs whose meaning would be defined on all platforms (even though on some platforms there might not exist any implementations that could process them), but which could still exploit abilities that are not universally supportable.  Unfortunately, I know of no way by which the Standard could be steered in that direction.

Comment: Thanks for your interest to the question! As far as I understand, the term "portability" _tends_ to include "ability to execute reproducibly", however, due to unspecified behaviors of execution environments (examples are "maximum amount of memory that can be allocated with malloc" [provided by user Chris Dodd] OR "amount of memory that is guaranteed to be allocated with malloc, ex. [1..1k bytes]"), there are no (in total) guarantees on the "execution aspect".

Comment: Consequences: (1) no absolute portability, (2) "shall _accept_ any strictly conforming program", rather than "run" or "execute reproducibly" (provided by user dxiv). Now the question: do execution environments based on virtual machines (VM) have the same issue with "ability to execute reproducibly"? In other words: do such VM based execution environments document all the "execution properties" in order to guarantee "ability to execute reproducibly"?

Comment: @pmor: Consider the question of what happens if an interrupt executes at a time when function calls are nested eight deep.  On some platforms, it may be impractical to meaningfully specify the possible consequences, and thus specifying that programs must behave predictably in such cases would make it impractical to produce conforming implementations for them.  On the flip side, on many larger platforms, an implementation that limited function call depth to a maximum of seven would be a toy which was unsuitable for many of the tasks such an implementation should be able to perform.

Comment: If one allows for the possibility that a conforming implementation may reject any program, then an implementation for a platform with a small hardware stack could reject any programs whose combined stack usage for the main-line and interrupt code could not be statically verified as being less than eight, and thus guarantee that provided user code never enabled interrupts from within an interrupt handler, no stack overflows could occur.  Conversely, an implementation for a larger machine might be able to inexpensively guarantee that any stack overflows that occur would trap...

Comment: ...in such a way as to yield documented behavior.  Such machines would be able to process a much wider range of programs than the small machine with the eight-level hardware stack, but stack-related issues would never cause UB on the smaller machine unless a program were to enable interrupts from within an ISR in a manner forbidden by the implementation's documentation.

Comment: Incidentally, the Standard contradicts itself in that it specifies both that an implementation must meaningfully process all strictly conforming programs (which would include programs that nest function calls millions of levels deep), but then specifies that if for some implementation there exists some program that exercises the Standard's specified translation limits, and which the implementation would process in a fashion consistent with the Standard, the implementation may impose whatever translation limits it wants on any other program, and behave arbitrarily if they're exceeded.